# iframe overflow parent div issue (grid-layout)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, css-grid

I have a grid layout with embedded youtube iframes inside.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="player">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iXr81W0Isxg" ?&controls="0&amp;showinfo=0&quot;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="player">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iXr81W0Isxg" ?&controls="0&amp;showinfo=0&quot;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrote styles for iframe to hide black youtube frames at the top and bottom

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.player {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 20px solid green;
}
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: -17%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 137%;
    transition: all 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But iframe overlaps parent div, ignore parent overflow: hidden; (parent has green border, to show you its area)

You can see it in this pen https://codepen.io/atvorch/pen/JLqqeG?editors=1100

This bug reproduce only in Chrome and only inside grid layout;
Seems like it's a Chrome grid-layout realization problem, but I'm not sure.
Will be grateful for any help or advice! (´ω｀)

Comment: possibly related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5H1jApRibw8

Comment: Could it be related to the Firefox overflow bug in grid layout, as mentioned on https://caniuse.com/#search=Grid? (And another question, half related: how do you deal with IE11 not supporting the current grid CSS?)